# Unexpected behavior of Java String split( )

Tags: java, parsing, split, whitespace

I am trying to split a string using String split function, here's an example:

```
    String[] list = "   Hello   ".split("\\s+");
    System.out.println("String length: " + list.length);
    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println("----");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
String length: 2
----

----
Hello
```

As you can see, the leading whitespace becoming an empty element in the String array, but the trailing whitespace is not.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Because that's exactly what the javadoc says? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) - *"This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.*

Comment: yea... I see @BrianRoach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [other split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) which specifys the limit and specify a limit of `-1`

```
String[] list = "   Hello   ".split("\\s+", -1);
```

to preserve the trailing whitespace, - the default behavior is to omit the trailing spaces as per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

---

Edit ([answer for comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006636/unexpected-behavior-of-java-string-split/18006665#comment26332504_18006665)):

To trim the leading space, you can strip off the leading space before splitting the `String`

```
String str = "   Hello   ".replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
String[] list = str.split("\\s+", -1);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Reimeus! What if I don't want the leading empty element in the array?  Is it possible not to write separate method to remove leading space?

Answer (score 2):

From [split documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

> This method works as if **by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero**. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

so in reality `split(regex)` is the same as using

```
split(regex, 0);
```

and its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) says

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit *n* is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most *n - 1* times, the array's length will be no greater than *n*, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If *n* is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.**

so if you want to include trailing empty strings will just have to use non-zero value like

```
split("\\s+",10);
```

but this will also limit result array to max 10 elements. To get rid of this problem use some negative number like

```
split("\\s+",-1);
```